# What's your recommended Google Analytics Extension for Magento 1.8.1?

Tags: extensions, google-analytics

Should I try with Fooman's? or their beta is not ready for production?

Forgot to say.... FREE extension... please.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about all your requirements, but Google Analytics is default option in Magento. You can find it under System -> Configuration -> Google API -> Google Analytics.